# Dynamic string wont change when changing the values that make it

Tags: javascript, json, string

http://jsfiddle.net/zzTsc/

I have a JSON that holds some values which get concatenated into a string but when I change the value of the JSON the string doesn't take the name values. How can I make the string take the new values without re-declaring the same string?

See I could easily put `string = name.first + "<br />"+name.last;` right below where I change the JSON value but then when I wanna edit the format of that string I'll have to change it twice.

Comment: are you expecting `string` to change automatically when `name.first` does?

Comment: You change `name`... not `string`. That's not how JS (or any other language?) works.

Comment: @Ibu  Yup. I want to change without having to redeclare it.

Comment: @sachleen Why would I want to change "string"? "name.first" is the value I want to change. I just want "string" to use the value from "name.first".

Comment: Yeah... but string is literally `"jimmy bob"` so you have to update its value

Comment: @sachleen that's what I'm asking, is there a way to "refresh" the string?

Comment: Yes... take a look at the answers below.

Comment: @sachleen I know that now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how variables work. You have to set the value of `string` again for it to update.

Here's an improved version so you don't have to change it twice if you want to edit something:

```
function generateString(name) {
    return name.first + "<br />"+name.last;
}
var string = generateString(name);
```

[​Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzTsc/3/)

Comment: NOO your's is better! I just +1d yours and was just about to delete mine.

Comment: Haha, ok if you say so. I undeleted mine but since you have a demo I think you should leave yours here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work as you describe it, but you could declare a function which returns the appropriate string.

So instead of

```
string = name.first + "<br />" + name.last;
```

You'd have:

```
var stringfunction = function() {return name.first + "<br />" + name.last;}
```

and when you wanted to use it you'd call it:

```
alert(string); //old
alert(stringfunction()); //new
```

EDIT: I just realized you're talking about changing the format (presumably at runtime). There are a number of ways to use string formats in javascript, meaning that you could have a "format" variable used inside the `stringfunction`, which you could change at runtime to modify how the resulting string is formatted. It's been too long since I used one of those tools though, so I'll leave it to someone else to explain how to do string formatting in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your string is a basic type and therefore holds the actual data instead of a pointer. When you change the data you think should change the string, it only changes the data. This can be seen by just re-issuing the code used to construct the string

```
$('#test').empty().append(name.first + "<br />"+name.last);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzTsc/4/

Comment: Whole reason I wanna use a single "string" variable is so I don't have to re-edit it in every place I put it if I feel like changing the format later.